# Can you split a group of particules between different forcefields?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I have a cube that emits particles surrounded by 4 cubes, each have a negative force fields (i.e. attractive). I want my population of particules to be equaly split between theses force fields to create an X pattern. However, the particles are only directed between the force fields and not directly on them. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please show your current work as a Blender Screen Capture.

Comment: I found the answer, the flow was too high so particles were not splitting. Now it works fine !

Comment: @JeffS please write an answer in the *answer section* so that other users can benefit from what you learned.

Comment: @Timaroberts I did, but it has been deleted by someone and placed in the comment section...

Comment: Maybe you can tell me in comment or whatever form that does not get deleted by  some BL .... Why the flow hindered and then helped you? I am curious since I do not use flow that much.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Sure, so based on my noob knowledge, I'd assume that have too much flow made particles "stick" to each other too much, resulting in a group behave as a single mass that was equally attracted to each forcefields... Just my interpretation though

Comment: Did this [assumption] come from some written document ... or was this some result you noticed in your experiments?  Of course the wonderful BL mechanism will soon inform us there are too many comments.  Which means you can put a response in the footnote of your question ... then we can erase some comments.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger No just something I notice while randomly tweaking